# How can I insert a table in the middle of a document with python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am using the python-docx library to modify an existing docx file. I want to add a table to the fifth line of the document. the issue is that when I use document.add_table( ), the table is added at the END of the document. I want to be able to choose WHERE to add the table in the document. Is there any way to do this? I wasn't able to find anything that worked online.

I Tried this :

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document('existing_document')

table_data = [
    ['Column 1', 'Column 2'],
    ['Data 1', 'Data 2'],
    ['Data 3', 'Data 4']
]

table = doc.add_table(rows=1,cols=2)
for i, row_data in enumerate(table_data):
    row = table.rows[i]
    for j, cell_data in enumerate(row_data):
        row.cells[j].text = cell_data

doc.save('modified_document.docx')
```

When I do this, the table is added to the end of the document.

I tried using insert_paragraph_before( ):

```
table = doc.add_table(rows=1,cols=2)

doc.paragraphs[5].insert_paragraph_before(table)
```

However, this triggered an error, as insert_paragraph_before seems to only works with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Is it mandatory to use python-docx?

By analyzing your code, I realized that you're using a template **'existing_document'**, so, in order to work with docx templates, I recommend using **docxtpl** instead.

Modify your template and add an empty table or tables with just headers to the place in the document you prefer.
[image: docx template]

Then, you can access to tables as easy as this:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
template = 'existing_document.docx'
output = 'output.docx'
doc = DocxTemplate(template)
doc.render({})

# Reading tables
tables = doc.tables
first_table = tables[0]
# Supposing you added a table with 3 columns(Fruit, Color, price)
rows = [['apple','red','1.5'], ['banana', 'yellow', '0.75']]
# Adding rows
for row in rows:
    table_row = first_table.add_row().cells
    table_row[0].text = row[0]
    table_row[1].text = row[1]
    table_row[2].text = row[2]
doc.save(output)
```

This is the resultant docx file:
[image: Result]

There are many ways to accomplish the same result using docxtpl, so take a look at its [documentation](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#tables)